# How do I get the text value of a selected option and use it as conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, cascadingdropdown

I'm using dynamic dropdown and getting values from database and then using option selected to make some conditional statements the drop down is built dynamically my code is as follows:

```js
function buscarHist(fgshgdjhgfgffjtfj) {
  $('.divHist').show();
  $('#down').html('');
  $.getJSON("./php/obtenerDatos.php", {
    IDA: fgshgdjhgfgffjtfj
  }, function(data) {
    var enca = Object.keys(data[0]);
    // console.log(enca);
    $.each(enca, function(i, item) {
      // $('#catalogos').append(item)
      $('#down').append('<option value ="' + data[0][item] + '" > ' + item + ' </option>')
      // console.log(item)

    });

  });
  $('#down').change(function() {
    $('#txtnombre').val($(this).val())
    // var mivalor = $('#txtnombre').val() 

  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {


      var AFIRMACIONES = [{
          display: "NO",
          value: "0"
        },
        {
          display: "SI",
          value: "1"
        }

      ];

      var AFIRMACIONES2 = [{
          display: "SI",
          value: "1"
        },
        {
          display: "NO",
          value: "0"
        }
      ];

      $(document).ready(function() {
        getSelectData($("#down"));
      });

      $("#down").change(function() {
        getSelectData($(this));

        function getSelectData(el) {
          var $option = el.find('option:selected');
          var text = $option.text();
          console.log(text);

          switch (text) {
            case 'PESO':
              list(AFIRMACIONES);
              break;
            case 'ZURDO':
              list(AFIRMACIONES2);
              break;

            default:
              $("#child_selection").html('');
              break;
          }

        }

        //  var parent = $(this).val();  
        //   console.log(parent)

        //  console.log(parent)

      });



      function list(array_list) {
        $("#child_selection").html("");
        $(array_list).each(function(i) {

          $("#child_selection").append("<option value=\"" + array_list[i].value + "\">" + array_list[i].display + "</option>");
        });
      }

      $('#child_selection').change(function() {
        $('#txtnombre').val($(this).val())

        //$("#txtnombre").hide();

        // }

      })
```

everything is working fine but I'm trying to use this piece of code to help me the get the value

```
   var $option = el.find('option:selected');
   var text  = $option.text();
   console.log(text);
```

It's supposed that

var text is bringing me the value 'PESO' which is ok but when I'm trying to use this value to switch conditional doesn't make anything. My question is is it possible to use this label as value? Because I can't use value 0 and 1 for example which would be the value inside PESO example ...

UPDATE:
Okay my dropdown is working dynamically and I'm retrieving data using this code which uses Json response

```
function buscarHist(fgshgdjhgfgffjtfj){
$('.divHist').show();
$('#down').html('');
$.getJSON("./php/obtenerDatos.php",{IDA:fgshgdjhgfgffjtfj}, function(data){
var enca =  Object.keys(data[0]);
// console.log(enca);
  $.each(enca,function(i,item){
   // $('#catalogos').append(item)
    $('#down').append('<option value ="' + data[0][item] + '" > '+ item +' </option>')  
    $("#down option:selected").text()
    if($("#down option:selected").text() == 'EDO_CIVIL'){
      $('#txtnombre').hide();
     // llenarNuevoDrop(ID_CATALOGO);
     //ocultarTEXT;
     //eventoCHANGEdelnuevoDROP();
    }
  });
```

and on my html code I'm only using this piece of code to show the dropdown menu and text box what I'm trying to achieve is call info from database and then edit certain values according to user choice I'm using this list because from database there are certain values which only work with catalogs for example 'ZURDO' appears as 1 or 0 on catalog and I must show 'SI' or 'NOT' , 'EDO_CIVIL' have this values inside the catalog '1','2','3' but obviously I can't show that value to user so I must use 'SOLTERO','CASADO','VIUDO' that's why I'm trying to achieve this now I believe because how am I calling the data on my parent dropdown is not showing on child's?

this is my code from HTML:

```
 </thead>                                    
   <select name="down" id="down" > 
                        
                             </select>
                             <select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
                              </select>
                            
                             <input id="txtnombre" type="text" class="form-control autofocus form-control-round F1" placeholder="SIN INFORMACION"/>
                             <input id="txtnombre2" type="text"  style="visibility:hidden" class="form-control autofocus form-control-round F1" placeholder="SIN INFORMACION"/>
```

Comment: if you use 'PESO' for both cases, then 'AFIRMACIONES' will always be passed to `list`, never 'AFIRMACIONES2'. review your data and update the question with more info

Comment: yes that's my mistake i've changed it to different value after 'PESO ' on switch statement but still it wont bring me the values from list by the way 'ZURDO' is another text that appears inside my dropdown i just want to know if i can use this labels as values  on my switch statement

Answer (score 0):

In this type of questions, you should post the relevant html code which is very useful. Things to consider:

1. Don't call `$(document).ready` twice, once is enough.
2. Don't declare functions (`getSelectData`) inside handlers (`$("#down").change`) or you'll end up redeclaring the same function over and over again.

As you can see, your logic was fine, the problem was the structure of the whole code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var AFIRMACIONES = [
    {
      display: "NO",
      value: "0"
    },
    {
      display: "SI",
      value: "1"
    }
  ];

  var AFIRMACIONES2 = [
    {
      display: "SI",
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      display: "NO",
      value: "0"
    }
  ];

  var AFIRMACIONES3 = [
    {
      display: "CASADO",
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      display: "SOLTERO",
      value: "2"
    },
    {
      display: "VIUDO",
      value: "3"
    }
  ];

  // $(document).ready(function() {
  getSelectData($("#down"));
  $('#txtnombre').val($('#child_selection').children(':selected').text())
  // });

  $("#down").change(function() {
    getSelectData($(this));
  });

  function getSelectData(el) {
    console.clear();
    var $option = el.find("option:selected");
    var text = $option.text();
    console.log(text);

    switch (text) {
      case "PESO":
        list(AFIRMACIONES);
        break;
      case "ZURDO":
        list(AFIRMACIONES2);
        break;
      case "EDO_CIVIL":
        list(AFIRMACIONES3);
        break;

      default:
        $("#child_selection").html("");
        break;
    }
  }

  function list(array_list) {
    console.log(array_list);
    $("#child_selection").html("");
    $(array_list).each(function(i) {
      $("#child_selection").append(
        '<option value="' + array_list[i].value + '">' + array_list[i].display + "</option>"
      );
    });
   $('#txtnombre').val($('#child_selection').children(':selected').text())
  }
  
  $('#child_selection').change(function() {
        $('#txtnombre').val($(this).children(':selected').text())

        //$("#txtnombre").hide();

        // }

      })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="down">
      <option value="1">PESO</option>
      <option value="2">ZURDO</option>
      <option value="3">EDO_CIVIL</option>
    </select>                                   
  
                             <select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
                              </select>

                             <input id="txtnombre" type="text" class="form-control autofocus form-control-round F1" placeholder="SIN INFORMACION"/>
                             <input id="txtnombre2" type="text"  style="visibility:hidden" class="form-control autofocus form-control-round F1" placeholder="SIN INFORMACION"/>
```

Comment: its working here but made changes to my code and still not showing the values from the list

Comment: @MewkOna well, I can't do much if you don't show your html and also the errors you are getting. update the question with your current html and js

Comment: find it odd because browser doesnt throw any error ,when i was using  var text  = $(this).val(); instead of .text  it was working perfectly but obviously that was bringing me the value, no the text (label ) and back then was working

Comment: yes but that part is done  for some reason the switch is still not working EDO_CIVIL ,ZURDO case arent showing the list i dont know if it is because my dropdown's dinamically

Comment: $('#down').append('<option value ="' + data[0][item] + '" > '+ item +' </option>')  ...this is how am i calling the data for my dropdown

Comment: @MewkOna there, I included EDO_CIVIL, but if you don't include EVERYTHING RELEVANT in your question, I cannot guess stuff, you need to explain what you need and show all relevant code in order for us to help

Comment: @MewkOna i saw `$('#down').append('<option value ="' + data[0][item] + '" > '+ item +' </option>')` in the question but remember we don't have access to `./php/obtenerDatos.php` so there is no way for us to know what `data` contains.

Comment: ./php/obtenerDatos.php only have one simple query where im calling all the data from user according to ID and brings me Json response

Comment: Including EDO_CIVIL wasnt relevant I know how to add that but is useless because on my code i cant use the .tex dropdown label to make the conditional statements wich is the only thing im missing